# How do i create and search html in jquery with GM_xmlhttpRequest?

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

How do i convert html text into a jquery object so i can do .find() and such?

I am grabbing a page with GM_xmlhttpRequest. I have the html of the page. Now with jquery i want to search a link. It had an id so its fairly easy however i have no idea how to make the html into a jquery object.

As a test i wrote `alert($('body').html());` which worked. However `alert($(thehtml).html());` gets me blank and IIRC i seen a few examples with hardcoded html inside of $('') but i could be remembering wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to call the html method. You can just pass an html string to the jQuery constructor, and it'll automatically create a jQuery object for you.

```
var someHTML = '<div><p>I am text inside of a "p" inside of a "div"</p></div>';

$(someHTML).find('p');
```

So, if you have your html string in a variable called `thehtml` and you want to find all the links in it, all you have to do is `$(thehtml).find('a')`.

Or, if you have an ID on that link, just do `$(thehtml).find('#theid')`.